# adding map feature on directory app [ANDROID]

Tags: android, dictionary, zooming

I'm currently working on a directory application on ANDROID.

it's my first time working on an mobile application.

While working for the app, I decided to add a map feature as well to locate buildings from the search result.
Instead of using google api, I'm trying to pinpoint the location on an image(map) I have.

since the image is really big as well. I want to zoom into the building when it's pinpointed.

Unfortunately, I don't know where to start.
The help will be really appreciated.

thank you.

Sincerely

Answer (score 1):

Google offer the static map API for free.

You can download a dynamically configured bitmap from the web, store it on the filesystem or on memory, then get a drawable from it in order to set it to the ImageView.

You need to generate an url from your coordinates to load the data from the web using this url. Exemple for a 200x200 bitmap showing the eiffel Tower in Paris:

```
String latEiffelTower = "48.858235";
String lngEiffelTower = "2.294571";
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latEiffelTower + "," + lngEiffelTower + "&zoom=15&size=200x200&sensor=false"
```

StackOverflow already have some answer on how to download an image from the web in order to display it in an imageview: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=imageview+url+%5Bandroid%5D

You can find here the documentation for the [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).